# Explaining this version of the proof of "Row operations do not change the row space"

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm self studying linear algebra and my textbook (Linear Algebra Done Wrong) tries to prove that "the row operations do not change the row space" however I don't understand the procedure.

Ran A is defined $Ran A=\left \{ \mathbf{w}\in W:\mathbf{w}=A\mathbf{v}~~for~some~\mathbf{v}\in V \right \}\subset W$

For a transformation $A$ and a set of $X$ let us denote by $A(X)$ the set of all elements $y$ which can represented as $y=A(x),x\in X$;$A(X):=\left \{ y=A(x):x\in X \right \}$.
If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $A_e$ is its echelon form, $A_e$ is obtained from $A$ by left multiplication $A_e =EA$, where $E$ is an $m\times m$ invertible matrix (the product of the corresponding elementary matrices). Then $Ran~A_e^T=Ran(A^TE^T)=A^T(Ran~E^T)=A^T(\mathbb{R}^m)=Ran~A^T$

---

Now, why $Ran(A^TE^T)=A^T(Ran~E^T)=A^T(\mathbb{R}^m)=Ran~A^T$?!

Comment: Interesting name for a book...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, since $A$ is a matrix I take it that it is being assumed that $V=\mathbb{R}^m$ for some $m$ and $W=\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$; for example, if $V$ is $m$-dimensional and $W$ is $n$-dimensional, then this is tantamount to choosing a basis for each and using this to establish a linear isomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $W$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$.  With this out of the way, we can get to the question itself.

Let's start with the definition: 
$$\operatorname{Ran} (A^\intercal E^\intercal)=\{ \mathbf{w}\in W \mid \text{$\mathbf{w}=(A^\intercal E^\intercal) \mathbf{v}$ for some $\mathbf{v}\in V$}\}$$
Now, matrix multiplication is associative, meaning that $(A^\intercal E^\intercal)\mathbf{v}$ is equal to $A^\intercal (E^\intercal \mathbf{v})$, and by our definition that $A(X)$ be defined as
$$A(X)=\{ \mathbb{w}\in W \mid \text{$\mathbb{w}=A \mathbb{v}$ for some $\mathbb{v}\in X$}\}$$ so that $\operatorname{Ran} A = A(V)$.  With this notation in mind, we see that
$$\operatorname{Ran} (A^\intercal E^\intercal)=A^\intercal (E^\intercal(V))=A^\intercal \operatorname{Ran} (E^\intercal)$$
I would assume that earlier in the text it is shown that row operations are invertible, so in particular 
$$\operatorname{Ran}(E^\intercal)=E^\intercal(V)=V=\mathbb{R}^m$$
and thus 
$$\operatorname{Ran}(A^\intercal E^\intercal)=A^\intercal \operatorname{Ran}(E^\intercal)=A^\intercal (\mathbb{R}^m)=A^\intercal(V)=\operatorname{Ran}(A^\intercal)$$